How to setup Edge browser not display dropdown with emails
In the Edge browser when I click on any email field it shows a dropdown with different emails. How can I setup Edge not to show that dropdown?


Do the following:

Go to Wallet settings
Go to section Personal info -> Settings:
Disable "Save and fill basic info"

